# Retrieve object from detected beacon

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I've created a scanning function, which register all regions from a `Content` object. However i can't seem to see how i am suppose to retrieve this Content object in the `didRangeBeacons` delegate method? this object contain information on what is suppose to be handled depending on the beacon?

**StartScanning**

```
func startScanning() {

    print(allContent[0].beacon?.UUID)

    for beacon in allContent {

        let uuid = NSUUID(UUIDString: beacon.beacon!.UUID)!
        let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: UInt16(beacon.beacon!.major), minor: UInt16(beacon.beacon!.minor), identifier: "MiniBeacon_10260")


        manager.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion)
        manager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)

    }


}
```

**didRangeBeacons**

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {

    if beacons.count > 0 {
        let beacon = beacons[0]
        updateDistance(beacon.proximity)
    } else {
        updateDistance(.Near)
    }
}
```

Here is an example of content object

```
class Content: Object{
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var date: NSDate = NSDate()
    dynamic var thumbnail: NSData = NSData()
    //Customization
    dynamic var navTitle: String = ""
    dynamic var navBarColor: String = ""
    dynamic var navButtonsColor: String = ""
    dynamic var beacon: Beacon?
    //Flags
    dynamic var isPresented: Bool = false
    dynamic var favorite: Bool = false
    dynamic var favoriteDate: NSDate = NSDate()


    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of your Content object?

Comment: From your question it is not clear what is `Content` object, how are you linked it to the Beacon. Bring more code with he created such and description

Comment: i've added an example of the content Object

Comment: How you want to get information about your custom object type from `CLBeacon` object? You need add dictionary with key with `UUID, major, minor` and value of your custom object. Then you can get it from dictionary  in `locationManager` method with information that contains in `CLBeacon` (`UUID, major, minor`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the app there must be a collection of `Content` objects.  In the first code snippet, there is a variable `allContent` that presumably represents this full list of objects.

What you can do is iterate through all of these content objects to find the one whose beacon identifiers matches the ranged beacon.  Something like this:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
  for rangedBeacon in beacons {
    for content in allContent {
      if let contentBeacon = content.beacon {

        if rangedBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString == contentBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString &&
           rangedBeacon.major.integerValue == contentBeacon.major.integerValue &&
           rangedBeacon.minor.integerValue == contentBeacon.minor.integerValue {
            // content now contains the content for rangedBeacon
            // TODO: do something with the matching content here
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above code is pretty brute force, and there may be a much more efficient way of doing this if you have your `Content` objects stored in CoreData or some other structure that is queryable by the beacon UUID/major/minor.

Comment: Okay i'm using realm for backend, would it be better to make a query to get the object rather than iterating ike you so here?

Comment: Yes, that would be more efficient.  But the same idea applies.